# Add a group column to a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df` like this

```
      V1 V2
1  13219  0
2   6358  1
3   4384  2
4   3359  3
5   2820  4
6   2466  5
7   2144  6
8   1941  7
9   1778  8
10  1550  9
```

and I would like to add a "`group`" column which will correspond to different value of `df$V2`.

```
At df$V2 = 0 group will be A
At df$V2 >0 <=5 group will be B
At df$V2 >= 6 group will be C
```

The idea would be to obtain something like this:

```
      V1 V2 Grp
1  13219  0 A
2   6358  1 B
3   4384  2 B
4   3359  3 B
5   2820  4 B
6   2466  5 B
7   2144  6 C
8   1941  7 C
9   1778  8 C
10  1550  9 C
```

This seems straight toward at first, but googling around doesn't help much. 
Advices much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `cut` or `findInterval`

```
df$Grp <- with(df, LETTERS[1:3][cut(V2, breaks=c(-Inf,0, 5, Inf),
            labels=FALSE)])

df$Grp <-  with(df, LETTERS[1:3][findInterval(V2, c(-Inf,0, 5,Inf)+1)])

df
#      V1 V2 Grp
#1  13219  0   A
#2   6358  1   B
#3   4384  2   B
#4   3359  3   B
#5   2820  4   B
#6   2466  5   B
#7   2144  6   C
#8   1941  7   C
#9   1778  8   C
#10  1550  9   C
```

Or

```
 with(df, LETTERS[c(2,1,3)][1+(V2==0) + 2*(V2 >=6)])
 #[1] "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C"
```

Comment: I would never have found this myself, Thanks.

Comment: For the record, I used this: 
labels=c("No","Low","Med","High")
df$Grp <- with(df, labels[cut(V2, breaks=c(-Inf,0, 5, 50, Inf),
                                    labels=FALSE)])

Comment: What is the +1 for in findinterval ?

Comment: @BenoitB. It is because of some difference in options in `?findInterval.

Answer (score 3):

Using indexing, this can be done quite easily:

```
df$group <- NA
df$group[df$V2 == 0] <- "A"
df$group[df$V2 > 0]  <- "B"
df$group[df$V2 >= 6] <- "C"
```

Note that the 3rd and 4th statements must be run in that sequence. Otherwise -- if you didn't want to have to run the "C" assignations after the "B" assignations, you'd need to define the indexing for the "B" assignations more thoroughly:

```
df$group[df$V2 > 0 & df$V2 < 6] <- "B"
```

**Results**

```
      V1 V2 group
1  13219  0     A
2   6358  1     B
3   4384  2     B
4   3359  3     B
5   2820  4     B
6   2466  5     B
7   2144  6     C
8   1941  7     C
9   1778  8     C
10  1550  9     C
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.csv(text="V1,V2
13219,0
6358,1
4384,2
3359,3
2820,4
2466,5
2144,6
1941,7
1778,8
1550,9")
```

Comment: This method will be both inefficient memory and time wise for a big data set. It is also prone for mistakes, and computationally inefficient if there are more than 3 conditions.

Comment: Well, not everyone works with huge databases. And for such a simple problem I think it's a perfectly viable option. For being prone to errors, I don't see your point. Mistakes can be done in many different ways and paying good attention is always required, no matter the method we choose.

Comment: Prone to errors is in the sense that you yourself correctly mentioned (and I quote) "*Note that the 3rd and 4th statements must be run in that sequence*"

Comment: _I_ didn't write that. But @Dominic gave an alternative to this sequential method, that is, specifying the full condifion.

Comment: Hey thanks @JasonV you're faster than me to defend my answer ;)

Comment: @JasonV I didn't see that you are the one that answered. BTW, I like how you guys upvoting each other and all, but it doesn't make you right. That other line is even worse that calls `df` 3 times in a single line and forces you to remember the logic in your head. What would happen if there were 20 different conditions? I would love to see how you would write these lines

Comment: Hehe well I use that method all the time and never caused any problems of performance/memory or errors, so I think it has its high merits. It's also more readable than other maybe marginally faster solutions, but often at the cost of diminished readability.

Comment: @DavidArenburg having 20 conditions would call for another approach. Doesn't make this one less interesting for small problems.

Comment: @JasonV how is it more readable than `cut`? Calling 20 condition won't change anyhting in both `cut` or `findInterval` approaches. R has special methods to deal with such problems, and writing all the condition by hand is just wrong from the above mentioned reasons.

Comment: Well then practically all introductury material to R should revise their approaches then. Seems you'll have a lot to people to convince. Good luck with that.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I think your first comment is a bit harsh. And I don't agree that this answer "is just wrong". But I agree that for more conditions a different approach would be required.

Comment: @docendodiscimus I didn't say that *this* answer is just wrong. I just said that for 20 conditions writing all the condition by hand is just wrong.

Comment: Noone's pretending the contrary. I agree that your way of commenting is a bit harsh. Let's not take this all that seriously, shall we? Anyhow, I'm off for tonight, cheers everyone.